# Passing objects in the linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, entities

I am using following linq statement in Web Api using entity framework. Everything is working fine except in my linq statement I dont know how to pass the ICollection

```
public class projOverview
{

    public int proj_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<p_type> p_type { get; set; }   
}
```

And the linq statement is

```
   var pOver= (from c in db.pr_d
                               select new pOver
                               {
                                   name=c.proj.name,
                                   proj_id=c.proj.p_id,
                                   p_type= ICollection<c.proj.pro_type>   
                               }).Take(7);
                return pOver;
```

I get intellisense error on  " p_type= ICollection" saying it is a type but used like a variable.
Please let me know how to fix it. Thank

Comment: What is the type of `c.proj.pro_type`?

Comment: is your `c.proj.pro_type` not `ICollection`?

Comment: look, do you have a class named `pOver` ? or mabe you want to write `select new projOverview{ 
name=c.proj.name, 
proj_id=c.proj.p_id,
p_type= ICollection<c.proj.pro_type> }).Take(7);`

Comment: What do you intend to do?

Comment: What I am trying to do is that get values of name and proj_id and p_type is values of a drop down so I can populate drop down and show the values of name and proj_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message should be helpful, you are setting p_type to a type (`ICollection<T>`) instead of a variable, you need to change to this:

```
   var pOver = (from c in db.pr_d
                         select new ProjOverview
                           {
                               name=c.proj.name,
                               proj_id=c.proj.p_id,
                               p_type= c.p_type_variable   
                           }).Take(7);
   return pOver;
```

I've also noticed that you used pOver as a class name, maybe you meant to use ProjOverview?

Answer (score 0):

when specifying a type, use the `typeof` operator

```
var pOver= (from c in db.pr_d
            select new pOver
            {
                name=c.proj.name,
                proj_id=c.proj.p_id,
                p_type= typeof(ICollection<c.proj.pro_type>)
            }).Take(7);
return pOver;
```